# Is temporarily overriding equals method possible?

Tags: java-7, equals, hashcode

Is there a way to *temporarily* override hashcode and equals in java ?
I have a `User` class with `id, name` and `age` attributes. The current `equals` compares the id, rightly so. So if two ids, are same then the Users are equal.

Now, I have two Lists of `User` and I want to find users with common names.

Other than looping every element of list1 over every element of list2, I have no other option (java 7). Is there a way, I can temporarily change the behaviour of `equals` ? In this case, where I am coding the logic for searching users with common names, I want to be able to say if name is same then the users are equal (even though its technically incorrect), without touching the actual `User` class's equal.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any benefit to overriding `equals` this way. If you were hoping to use `contains`, that would still perform the loop you want to avoid, just hidden away. This sounds like a job for a `Map`.

Comment: Don’t override equals and hashcode. What you’re looking for is called a Comparator.

Comment: @user2357112 Agreed. At least it will be the standard java api doing this stuff. Although I wonder if converting two lists to a map and then somehow doing what I want to do would be cost-effective.

Comment: @NathanHughes I am not looking to sort the elements. I have never used a Comparator to achieve what I am trying to do. Any examples ?

Comment: Instead of trying to hide the expensive operation, you should replace it by an efficient solution, loop over one list, putting all elements into a `HashMap`, mapping from the desired property (name) to the element, followed by looping over the other list looking up the names. That’s n+m operations instead of n×m operations…